# "You drew against your friend. None of you earned bonus points." Does this phrase sound natural?

Tags: phrase-usage

In the context of an e-learning game, where a friend can challenge another, the one who gets more points answering wins the challenge. If they draw, neither of them gets the bonus points. Would the following phrase sound natural in a notification?

**"You drew against your friend. None of you earned bonus points."**

Comment: I assume the context is *you drew [your weapon] against a friend* (having momentarily mistaken him for "the enemy" in a *shoot 'em up* game). Since there are only two players involved, it should be *[Therefore/so] **neither** of you earned [any] bonus points*.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I assume this is at the end of the game - neither player won or lost, it was a draw. I agree that, if there are only 2 players, _"neither"_ is better than _"none"_.

Comment: @SteveES: I don't know much about such games, but it's not obvious to me why the friend should be denied bonus points just because someone [*the* other player?] mistook him for a foe. Perhaps good players are supposed to avoid putting themselves into situations where this type of identification error might happen.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I was assuming a 1v1 game, e.g. chess, where you are playing against a "friend", e.g. on a social media platform. If this is not the case, then the phrase would seem odd to me, it probably should be "opponent" rather than "friend".

Comment: @SteveES is correct, it means it was a draw...and there are only two players

Comment: @SteveES, it is in a e-learning game...a friend can challenge another, the one who gets more points answering wins the challenge

Comment: @Filipe: You should edit your *question text* to reflect that, rather than drip-feeding essential details in comments. If the situation involves ***draw = gain equal scores*** rather than ***draw = unholster weapon***, I'm tempted to wonder why the game-writer would assume the person playing against the addressee must be a "friend".

Comment: Ditto to Fumble Fingers. Ii cannot stand drip-feeding essential details. There is nothing more annoying in questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you are talking about a match, combat or fight that ended in a draw, I'd suggest this:

> The match/fight/combat against your friend ended in a draw. Neither of you earned bonus points

The one you suggested is confusing, because reading it you can either understand that a player drew a weapon against a friend, or that there was a combat/match/whatever that ended in a draw.

Answer (score -1):

There is nothing specifically wrong with it and sure, such a statement can fit withing the context of a game.